# Rounding error on percent of total and back

Tags: javascript, math

A and B are integers.

Is it **certain**, with all the complexities of rounding errors in JavaScript, that:

`(A/(A+B))*(A+B) === A`

This is to say that if the user enters 10, and 20 for A and B respectively, can I store the summed total (30) with A = .33333333 and B = .66666666 and later multiply the sum by these decimals to get back to the value of 10 (with no rounding error)?

Comment: You should either use some sort of rounding tollerant comparison or google for a library implementing rational numbers. For example rational.js or fraction.js. BTW not only rounding but number representation itself yeilds comparison problems. Try `0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3`

Comment: I'm aware of the situation you presented.  Is it still the case when A and B are both integers?

Comment: Oh, also in my equation, there doesn't seem to be an scenario where you'd add or multiply two decimals. Though, obviously you'd multiply a decimal and an int.

Comment: Just curious. Do you have some sort of use-case for this or are you just exploring the way the mathematics works?

Comment: I have a specific use case.  It's rather hard to convey, but it has to do with wanting to store the RESULT of a user's input vs the numbers the user actually enters.  So the user sees two rows, they enter 10 and 20, I don't want to store 10 and 20 I want to store a total of 30 and 1/3 and 2/3 respectively.  In this way I can make it consistent with another type of user entry in which the user enters the 1/3 and 2/3 and doesn't enter the 30 until later.  Kinda hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Well I set out to answer my own question with some easy scripting.

Here's what I ran:

```
var maxDifference = 0;

var assert = function (a, b) {
  var derivedA = (a/(a+b))*(a+b);
  if (!(derivedA === a) && (a - derivedA) > maxDifference) {
    console.log('----\nFound new biggest difference');
    console.log('a:', a);
    console.log('b:', b);
    console.log('difference:', (a - derivedA));
    maxDifference = a - derivedA;
  }
}

for (var a = 1; a < 10000000; a++) {
  for (var b = 1; b < 10000000; b++) {
    assert(a, b);
  }
}

console.log('Max Difference:', maxDifference);
```

What I found is that there CAN be a difference. That difference is something like `(2^n)*Number.EPSILON` where `n` is (so far) 15.  This is about: `3.9968028886505635e-15`

Rounding **seems** to be a safe way to reliably get back to the original int.