# Why is the maximum error for this equation 4096*Number.EPSILON?

Tags: javascript, math

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761856/rounding-error-on-percent-of-total-and-back) I wrote a script to find the maximum error that can arise from storing a value as a fraction of a sum and then going back again.

I found that the maximum error is related to Number.EPSILON:

`maximumError / Number.EPSILON` is a nice round number, 8192.
`Math.log2(8192)` is a 12.999999999999998, so... 13.

What's the relationship between this rounding error and Number.EPSILON?

Why is it a nice factor of 2?  What does the 13 "mean"?

UPDATE: Script just found a maximum error of 3.637978807091713e-12 which divided by Number.EPSILON is 16384.  Math.log2(16384) ~= 14.

Comment: `Number.EPSILON` is `2^-52`. `8192` is `2^13`. Therefore by algebra, `maximumError` must be `2^-39`. I can't tell you much more about what `2^-39` "means" without seeing the code that creates or uses `maximumError`, I think.

Comment: Check out the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761856/rounding-error-on-percent-of-total-and-back question for the code.  The question is WHY does this code produce a maximum error that is a factor of Number.EPSILON.  And does 13 relate to that number by way of saying that's the maximum number of bits wrong or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of any floating point value greater than 1 (or less than -1) divided by `Number.EPSILON` *must* be an integer. (This is not necessarily true of values exclusively inside the range `1` to `-1`.)

Recall that floating points are a 2-tuple of bit strings `(m,e)` (mantissa and exponent) where the value of the number they represent is `m * 2^e`. The mantissa sets the value as a bitstring, and the exponent shifts the bits to a certain power  In the current ECMAScript 6 draft, the definition of `Number.EPSILON` is:

> the difference between 1 and the smallest value greater than 1 that is representable as a Number value

We derive epsilon by taking a mantissa of `1000...0001` (`1` in the largest and smallest digits in the mantissa bitstring) and a negative exponent that shifts the mantissa down to the binary value `1.000...0001`. Substract the `1`, and you have epsilon. Note that this is *not* the smallest possible floating-point value, but it *is* the smallest level of precision available to a floating-point value greater than 1 (or less than -1).*

As for why you always produce an integer, that easy to explain: epsilon is the *smallest possible precision value* for numbers greater than 1. It is not possible for epsilon to divide a value greater than 1 unevenly, because that would suggest the number had some fractional part that is smaller than epsilon, which is definitionally impossible (since epsillon is the smallest level of precision for `>1` numbers). Feel free to drum on your number pad and divide that number by `Number.EPSILON` -- you'll see the result is an integer.

As for why the results are always powers of 2, this appears to be because all your `maximumError` results so far have a mantissa that is also a power of 2 (possibly they all have a mantissa of `1`), so it's just division between powers of 2 (therefore the result must also be a power of 2).

Notice that all of the `a` values that produce this case are those that have a `1` in the lowest bit, so they are of the form `(2^n) + 1` (and `1` itself): `5`, `9`, `33`, `65`, etc. It appears that there is some mathematical property in play here where the multiplication doesn't restore the full value, and the original `100...001` value becomes `100...000.1111111111...`. It's off by some very tiny amount, `0.000000...000001`. The format of this number is expressed as `1 * 2^-n`, so the mantissa is always `1`.

You might find binary representations by `num.toString(2)` of interest: for very large or very small values, it clearly shows the binary mantissa offset by zeros, caused by the exponental bit shift of the `* 2 ^ e`. For example, see the maxed-out, bit-shifted mantissa in  `Number.MAX_VALUE.toString(2)`:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

In fact, the only reason the error is growing is because the number of trailing `1`s in `100...000.1111111111...` is decreasing due to the fixed size of the mantissa. Consider:

```
> var a = 9, b = 510; ((a/(a+b))*(a+b)).toString(2);
"1000.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
> var a = 17, b = 4194; ((a/(a+b))*(a+b)).toString(2);
"10000.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Note that those strings are exactly the same length, but the left of the decimal point is one digit larger in the second case. That's because the mantissa is only big enough to hold a certain number of binary digits. What should logically be an infinite number of `1`s becomes only as many `1`s as will fit in the floating point number. Consider the analogous situation in decimal, where [0.999... is actually equal to 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...); thus, in binary `0.11111...` is equal to `1`, but we don't have the space to express infinite digits.

Since the number of tailing ones decreases as the left of the decimal point grows, the error margin grows as well, since `0.000...0001` gets closer and closer to the decimal point.

---

*: Consider a simple mantissa like `10001`. If you wanted to use that mantissa to make a value as small as possible, you could use a hugely negative exponent to produce a value like `0.00000000000010001`. However, if you needed to keep the value greater than `1` (as you do when considering the definition of `Number.EPSILON`), you can only shift it down to `1.0001`. How far that final `1` can go is bounded by the size of mantissa, when the leading `1` must stay on the left of the decimal place. If you're merely trying to create the smallest value and can go less than 1, you can shift the mantissa much farther to the right.

Comment: This is a great answer and clears things up for me.  Thank you!  Can you speak to what makes it such that this operation has a mantissa of one?  Is that because by "A" and "B" variables in my operation are integers?

Comment: @AdamTerlson I looked into the problem a little more (floating points are very interesting!) and added significantly more information.

Comment: I see that.  Thanks!  Super interesting indeed.

Comment: Great answer! It might be interesting to note that your first sentence does not hold true for floating-point numbers below `1`. This is easily explained [through how MDN defines `Number.EPSILON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON): "...represents the difference between one and the smallest value greater than one..."

Comment: Though that brings up the issue of whether your definition "epsilon is the smallest possible value" is truly correct.

Comment: @yerforkferchips Okay, I finally got it: you can have fractional values *way* less than `Number.EPSILON`. The "one" value used in deriving the value not only uses up a digit, but it also tethers the exponent. You can max out the negative exponent and send your mantissa very far to the right. However, if you need your value to be greater than `1`, you can only augment the negative exponent until the highest digit of the mantissa is the ones place. For a mantissa of `10001`, you could make it `0.00000000010001`, but to have it greater than `1`, you can only make it `1.0001`.

Comment: That's quite the academic discussion now. I think I'm going to have to come back to this with a glass of wine some time... In the meantime, do you think it's worth updating your answer (or at least refer to these comments)?

Comment: @yerforkferchips Updated; I'm afraid it's a bit more complicated now, but hopefully still understandable.